# MySQL Workbench 8.0.28 export issue on MacOS 12.3

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Up until recently I was using MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 without any issues till I upgraded my MacOS to 12.3 after which the Workbench software itself stopped working. I then upgraded my Workbench version to 8.0.28 (latest version at the time of writing).

But after updating to the new version, I initially had issues connecting to my remote databases. I was getting the following error -

`Got error: 2026: SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol when trying to connect`

But I was able to solve that one by setting the 'Use SSL' option under the SSL tab for the connection to 'No'.

The next issue though is now I am not able to perform exports on the server using mysqldump. The Workbench software is trying to run the following command -

`Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump --defaults-file="/var/folders/fd/jt76prtj4z35dqd6y1y1_jcw0000gn/T/tmppuwxrtig/extraparams.cnf"  --host=host.db.com --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --user=logicspice --protocol=tcp --single-transaction=TRUE --column-statistics=0 --skip-triggers "database"`

after which I'm getting a similar issue -

`mysqldump: Got error: 2026: SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol when trying to connect`

Is there an update I can do to a certain configuration file for either mysqldump or MySQL Workbench that will disable the use of SSL when trying to use mysqldump?

Your assistance would be much appreciated as this issue is causing delays in my development work. Thanks!

```
Summary of system - 
Operating system - MacOS Monterey 12.3
Processor - 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
MySQL Workbench version - mysql-workbench-community-8.0.28-macos-x86_64.dmg
MySQL version - 5.6.10 (MySQL Community Server (GPL)) on AWS RDS
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

## Exporting a MySQL or MariaDB database

To export the database, the mysqldump command is used from the console. Once the backup is done, the generated file can be easily moved. To start exporting the database you have to execute the following:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > data-dump.sql
```

- **username :** Refers to the name of the database user.
- **database_name :** Must be replaced by the name of the database you want to export.
- **data-dump.sql :** Is the file that will be generated with all the database information.

That command will not produce any visual output. So, to make sure that the SQL copy has been performed correctly, you can inspect the generated file to make sure that it is a SQL copy. To do this you can use the following statement:

```
head -n 5 data-dump.sql
```

That command should return something like this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database_name
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.7.16-0 ubuntu 0.16.04.1
```

It is also possible to export one or more tables instead of the entire database. To do this, you must indicate in the command the selection you want to make.

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name table_name_1 table_name_2 table_name_3 > data-dump.sql
```

In this case, it is important to take special care with the relationships between the different records. When importing, only those tables that have been selected will be overwritten.

## Importing a MySQL or MariaDB database

To import a MySQL or MariaDB dump, the first thing to do is to create the database into which the import will be done. To do this, if you do not have any database manager, you have to connect to the database server as "root" user.

```
mysql -u root –p
```

This will open the MySQL or MariaDB shell. You will then be able to create the database.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE new_database;
```

If everything went well, you will see something like this:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Once created, you have to exit this shell by pressing CTRL+D. Once you are in the normal command line, it will be time to launch the command that will perform the database import.

```
mysql -u username -p new_database < data-dump.sql
```

- **username :** Is the name of the user with access to the database.
- **new_database :** Is the name of the database where the import will be performed.
- **data-dump.sql :** Is the name of the file containing all the sql statements to be imported.

If any errors occur during the import process, they will be displayed on the screen. As you can see, exporting and importing a MySQL or MariaDB database is a very simple process.

**Note :** All this is done with Ubuntu in a terminal but in MAC it is exactly the same .

**Another solution :** In case you still get that error I have found assuming you are using OpenSSL and not ysSSL.

Refer to the MySQL configuration variable ssl_cipher. [<kbd>ssl_cipher</kbd>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ssl_cipher)

Configure a list of ciphers including pseudo-encryption `@SECLEVEL=1`

For example :

```
ssl_cipher = "DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:@SECLEVEL=1"
```

If you need a more permissive but still secure encryption list.

```
"EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:@SECLEVEL=1"
```

taken from https://cipherlist.eu/ could do the job.